# Converting CRS with geopandas gives wrong coordinate values

Tags: python, coordinates, transformation, geopandas, pyproj

I'm trying to convert a bunch of geometries using geopandas from EPSG:4326 (wgs84) to EPSG:31370 (belgium lambert 72)

I was trying a small test but the coordinates that I get are incorrect.

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

#Some location in Belgium
point1 = shapely.geometry.Point(51.2, 3.2)
row = {"z": [2.1], "geometry": [point1]}

#Assign crs to wgs84
point_wgs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(row, crs=4326)

point_bel = point_wgs.to_crs(31370)
```

I'm getting coordinates 6684560.556, -3548962.482 as a result, but the correct coordinates should be something around 68000, 210000.
I tried with pyproj as well as

```
from pyproj import Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:31370")
belgian_point = transformer.transform(point_wgs.iloc[0].geometry.x, point_wgs.iloc[0].geometry.y)
```

And Im getting the correct result. What's going on?

I would like to use geopandas since I have multiple different features.

Comment: These issues are *always* caused by flipped lat/lon values, until proven otherwise. =)

Comment: Ohhhhh, you are absolutely right. I just flipped them and it works :facepalm: . Thank you very much for replying!

Comment: And I would use CRS like in pyproj: use strings (less possibility system will confuse them)